# Execute cross thread function one by one

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading

I have some special functions in my project, they will execute cross many threads, such as childContext perform block or AFNetwork response block:

```
(void)my_function {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSManagedObjectContext *childContext = [[[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType] autorelease];
        childContext.parentContext = self.managedObjectContext;
        [childContext performBlock:^{
            [self.operationManager POST:URL parameters:nil block:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
                //Do something
                [childContext performBlock:^{
                    //Do something
                }];
            }];
        }];
    });
}
```

Now I want to execute them one by one (including all blocks in function). After reading a couple of other answers, some of the Apple documentation, I get some answers:

### 1. NSRecursiveLock

I can add NSRecursiveLock for each function, but the issue is that I can't lock/unlock cross thread.

```
(void)my_function {
    [MyLock lock];    // Lock here
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSManagedObjectContext *childContext = [[[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType] autorelease];
        childContext.parentContext = self.managedObjectContext;
        [childContext performBlock:^{
            [self.operationManager POST:URL parameters:nil block:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
                //Do something
                [childContext performBlock:^{
                    //Do something
                    [MyLock unlock];    //Unlock here
                }];
            }];
        }];
    });
}
```

### 2. NSOperation

I can add each function to NSOperationQueue as a NSOperation, and set concurrent operation number to 1, but the issue is that I can't make sure the code in block has been executed even the NSOperation finishes successfully.

### 3. @synchronized

I can add @synchronized, but has same issue as NSOperation

Comment: Do you mean you want execute `my_function ` many times and they should execute one after another

Comment: No, I have some different functions, but same to my_function, they will execute cross many threads. I want to execute them one by one

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is using `NSOperationQueue` and `Asynchronous NSOperation`.

You can make sure operation execute one by one in two ways

- `addDependency:`
- Set `maxConcurrentOperationCount` to 1

With `Asynchronous NSOperation`,it is you to decide when this Operation is done.

For example

```
-(void)my_function {
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    NSManagedObjectContext *childContext = [[[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType] autorelease];
    childContext.parentContext = self.managedObjectContext;
    [childContext performBlock:^{
        [self.operationManager POST:URL parameters:nil block:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
            //Do something
            [childContext performBlock:^{
                //Do something
                //Only mark this NSOperation is done when all task of this function is finished.
            }];
        }];
    }];
});
}
```

How to make an `Asynchronous NSOperation`,This is what I usually do,you can also refer it in the document.

1. Keep two property

   ```
   @interface AsyncOperation (){
       BOOL finished;
       BOOL executing;
   }
   ```
2. Use these two property to manage Operation state

   ```
   -(BOOL)isFinished{
      return finished;
   }
   -(BOOL)isExecuting{
       return executing;
   }
   ```

   3.Mark `Operation` start

Note:start function is called on the thread the Operation created

```
    -(void)start{
    if ([self isCancelled])
    {
       // Must move the operation to the finished state if it is canceled.
        [self willChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];
        finished = NO;
        [self didChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];
        return;
    }  

     // If the operation is not canceled, begin executing the task.
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(main) toTarget:self    withObject:nil];
    executing = YES;
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];
    }
```

4. Mark Operation is done

I use this function

```
    -(void)setOperationFinished{
       [self willChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];
       [self willChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];
       executing = NO;
       finished = YES;
       [self didChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];
       [self didChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"]; 
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Leo, how to mark a NSOperation is done? From Apple's document, I only know how to cancel, https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperation_class/

Comment: See my update,you can also refer it from the document